# Get json_encode value

Tags: jquery, json

I've little experience in json. We get external data through the following function:

```
var params = {
...
},
translate: {
    ...
},
data: {
    customerObject:    <?= json_encode($this->customer->toArray()) ?>,
    windings: <?= json_encode($this->windings)?>
},
cache: {
    shapes: {}
},
modals: {}
};
```

The windings var gets the following data delivered in the page source:

```
windings: {"0":"base64 png value", "1":"base 64 png value", "2":"base 64 png value", ...}
```

I need to get the base64 png values into an already existing selectbox (the selectbox already has the correct number of options with the correct value (0, 1, 2, ..).

Could anybody please help me?

Comment: What you want to here actually .Whether you want keys of windings or values of windings.You can use JSON.parse(data.windings). here you will get object and then you can play with your stuffs.

Comment: Use square-bracket notation: `windings[0]`. As for me, this windings object should be array instead: `windings: ["base64 png value", "base 64 png value"]`

Comment: Not very clear, as i said i have very little experience in json. How would i for example append every base64 png value to the body?

Comment: JSON is just a data format. What you asking is a Javascript. Give us a clear question and you'll get a clear answer.

Comment: Then i guess my question is more javascript. I simply need to add the png values to the already existing selectbox values.

Comment: It's not that simple if you want your png rendered to picture, because selectboxes don't do that. You will need some plugin for any popular framework which rendered custom selectbox with picture. Or you need just text base64 representation of picture (for whatever)?

Comment: That's a problem for later :) The ideal solution would be to have an extra value added to the options:

<option value="1" img-data="base64value">1</option>

I have my eyes on a jquery plugin which can use the img and put it in the selectbox value.

Comment: You probably need something like I posted to answer. Of course you will need to adapt in to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on explanations in comments:

```
var options = $("#myselectbox").find("option");
for (var idx in windings) {
    options.eq(idx).prop("img-data", wingings[idx]);
};
```

Comment: This seems to look fine, except for the fact that it can't find windings. Probably because i haven't fetched my array?

Comment: I can't say anything based on current info in question. Of course you need variable windings defined and filled.

Comment: It's okay, i filled up my js array and everything is fine now. Thanks!